# How do I downgrade Android 2.1 to 1.6 on a Garminfone?

Tags: 2.1-eclair

I need to send in my Garminfone to T-Mobile. I've rooted it and installed the 2.1 upgrade. The master reset doesn't restore it to 1.6. I know Super One Click will unroot it. Does anyone know how to revert back to 1.6? Thanks.

Comment: From what you're asking it sounds unlikely, but did you do any kind of system backup before/after rooting, and definitely before loading a custom ROM? I think you're going to have problems finding a download of the original ROM anywhere as Garmin are *extremely* protective of their map app and data which will be embedded in any original ROM.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the root process for Garminfone, but if you have access to your bootloader (usually termal like with a list of options) just put a 1.6 stock rom on your sd card and flash it.

I tried googleing "stock 1.6 garminfone rom" with no success, probably because of what GAThrawn said, but someone over at xda-developers might have something if want to go check out there forums.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be an update for 1.6, but I'm not sure how you'd load it.  http://www.garminasus.com/en_US/support/software/006-B1130-00.update